# MVC ViewModel not posting back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Viewmodel, however when I submit the form, I am not getting the values back.

I have a Model Like this...

```
Public Class ProductSummaryModel

    Property productGUID As Integer
    Property productName As String
    Property productPrice As Double
    Property productSku As String
    Property categories As String()
    Property ShipsWithin As Nullable(Of Integer)
    <AllowHtml>
    Property productWebDescription As String
    Property ImageMainPath As String

End Class
```

Then I have a ViewModel Like this...

```
Public Class ProductViewModel
    Public ProductSummary As ProductSummaryModel
End Class
```

Here is my Controller...

```
Public Function Add() As ActionResult ' Default View To Add  Item
    Dim prdsummary As ProductViewModel = New ProductViewModel
    Return View("Add", prdsummary)
End Function
```

in my "Add" View I have following...

```
<tr>
    <td>Price: </td>
    <td><%=Html.TextBoxFor(Function(f) f.ProductSummary.productPrice)%></td>
</tr>
```

Problem is, when I submit the FORM, I cant get the POSTED Form Values.

```
    Public Function AddItem(ByVal Model As ProductViewModel) As ActionResult ' Add Item into DB

        Dim ajaxMessage As New AjaxFormResponse

        Dim prd As ProductSummaryModel = New ProductSummaryModel
        Model.ProductSummary = prd

        Dim skuID As Integer = 0
        msgbox(Model.ProductSummary.categories) ' Empty

End Function
```

May there is a better way of handling this.

*** UPDATE ******

I  have figured out what the Problem is...When passing Model to ViewModel I had to do this...

```
Dim Product As ProductViewModel = New ProductViewModel
Dim ProductSummary As New ProductSummaryModel
Product.ProductSummary = ProductSummary
Return View("Add", Product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the ProductSummaryModel for binding instead of ProductViewModel. This way you can keep thing simple. Avoid nested bindings if you can.
Also be sure you have using in the view as below, and the HttpPost attr. in the Controller

**Product Controller**

```
Public Class ProductController
Inherits Controller

' Main Action
Public Function Main() As ActionResult 
    Dim prdViewModel As ProductViewModel = New ProductViewModel       
    prdViewModel.ProductSummary = New ProductSummaryModel
    Return View("Main", prdViewModel)
End Function

' Partial Action
Public Function Add() As ActionResult 
    Dim prdViewModel As ProductViewModel = New ProductViewModel
    prdViewModel.ProductSummary = New ProductSummaryModel

    Return View("Add", prdViewModel)
End Function

'POST Action from Partial View
<HttpPost()> _
 Public Function AddItem(ByVal Model As ProductSummaryModel) As ActionResult ' Add Item into DB
   msgbox(Model.productPrice) ' Empty
End Function

End Class
```

**Main View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MvcApplication2.ProductViewModel)" %>

<asp:Content ID="manageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Main Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="manageContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%
        Html.RenderPartial("_Add", Model.ProductSummary)
     %>
</asp:Content>
```

**Partial View**

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MvcApplication2.ProductSummaryModel)" %>

<asp:Content ID="registerTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Register
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="registerContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% Using Html.BeginForm("AddItem", "Product")%>
        <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
        <tr>
            <td>Price: </td>
            <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(f) f.productPrice) %></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    <% End Using%>
</asp:Content>
```

**UPDATE VIEW MODELS**

```
 Public Class ProductSummaryModel

    Property productGUID As Integer
    Property productName As String
    Property productPrice As Double
    Property productSku As String
    Property categories As String()
    Property ShipsWithin As Nullable(Of Integer)
    <AllowHtml>
    Property productWebDescription As String
    Property ImageMainPath As String

End Class

Public Class ProductViewModel
    Public ProductSummary As ProductSummaryModel
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Spock, This is how I was doing it before, Problem is...I have multiple TABS, and each TAB is a partial view Itself. Each Tab will contain its own ViewModel, and then I will send my main Model (ProductViewModel) to by DB, instead of passing multiple / Separate ViewModels.

Comment: In your Main View which has the partial view, use Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MvcApplication2.ProductViewModel)". Your partial view use the above  solution I posted. When you call this as a Partial view from the Main view, for example Html.RenderPartial("_YourProduceSummaryPartialView, Model.ProductSummaryModel"). And of course in your partial View @ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MvcApplication2.ProductSummaryModel)" %>

Comment: Here is more information on setting up a Partial View http://forums.asp.net/p/1908088/5399482.aspx?Re+Html+RenderAction+causes+application+to+hang

Comment: Yes I did that, but now when I try to Post the Form and try to get the Values back, i am getting Object instance Error Message. this is how my Controller looks like:
Public Function AddItem(ByVal Model As ProductViewModel) As ActionResult ' Add Item into DB
 MsgBox(Model.ProductSummary.productName)

Comment: Which line you get Object instance Error?

Comment: @highwingers I have updated my solution. With Parial View. This should atleast point you to the right direction.

Comment: COuld you please post ProductSummaryModel & ProductViewModel Class also?

Comment: @highwingers updated the answer with ViewModels. I don't know how to join the chat as SO suggested me:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41743/discussion-between-spock-and-highwingers)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems :

First, you're overriding posted values when you do this :

```
Dim prd As ProductSummaryModel = New ProductSummaryModel
Model.ProductSummary = prd
```

The `ProductSummary` property in the model coming from your view is lost and you only get default values when you read its properties.

Also, you don't show how you set `categories` values in your view. Are you allowing user inputs or some other operation for this property ?

Comment: I created a new instance of productsummary, becaise i was getting Null instance expection. Yes, category is coming from a form field... To keep the question simple i did not post that part. ProductSummary is a object itself within my viewmodel, however when i try to access my viewmodel i get exception.